# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {author})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js, sanity

[this is my sanity schema called blogs and there is one refrence field called author](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kckX0.png)

[so i am using blog.author to get author name on my blog getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWAI0.png)

code in sanity blog.js

```
  {
        name: 'author',
        type: 'object',
        fields: [
          {
            title: 'Author',
            name: 'author',
            type: 'reference',
            to: [{type: 'author'}]
          }
        ]
      }
```

code in nextjs slug.js page

{blog.author}

getting error

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {author}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: I've never used sanity, but react is telling you the problem it has. `blog.author` is an object and that is not supported as a `ReactNode`.  Swap `{blog.author}` to `<pre>{JSON.stringify(blog.author ?? {}, null, '\t')}</pre>` and React will happily print out the JSON of the object for you. As to if/why `blog.author` is an object would require me to look at what sanity is, so someone else is probably better suited to answering that question.

Comment: Please make sure to post code as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Instead of declaring your initial state with NULL try to use array !

Answer (score 0):

As Jacob said, `blog.author` is an object. You likely want to output something like `blog.author.name` (but it's hard to know without seeing your `author` schema). You'll also want to make sure you're [dereferencing](https://www.sanity.io/docs/groq-operators#dae298fc7952) (i.e., following the reference to) `author` in your query.